# Terminating solid Ethernet in a pull out rack

Tags: ethernet, cable, wiring, rack

How should I terminate solid Ethernet cable in a shallow rack?

#### Information

1. I've wired my house with solid CAT7.
2. It terminates in a double gang.
3. The wiring cabinet can fit a 300mm equipment rack
4. The rack will have some equipment that's not full length

[image: wiring]

#### Thoughts

1. Should I try and terminate it on the wall and go stranded?

[image: panel]

[AKORD CAT6 12 Port Pro RJ45 110 Network Mini Patch Panel w/Surface Wall Mount Bracket](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AKORD-Network-Patch-Surface-Bracket/dp/B00JS604AS/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1532349309&sr=1-1&keywords=mini%20patch%20panel%20wall%20mount)

2. If the rack is pull out will the solid cable fatigue from repeated (infrequent) bending?
3. Should I go with a fixed rack and live with reduced accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that punchdown block will work. I would suggest mounting it to a fixed rack and never touching it again. Then you can plug whatever you want in to that patch panel. What is reducing the accessibility? Your patch panel can be eye-level at the front of the rack.

Comment: for accessibility I just meant getting into the back of it. I did originally buy a 1u patch panel and keystone punch downs. should I just fix the rack and add sliders to the panels that need it?

Comment: I wonder if you could mount the patch panel vertically so that the wires come out the top and bottom? It would be ugly but practical for your concerns. Honestly, I'm more concerned about your ventilation than your wiring.

Comment: yes cooling is a concern, I'm looking at intake at the top back and exhaust on the bottom front. but that's probably a question for another time

Comment: Remember that heat rises. You want to exhaust out the ceiling of the room and intake cold air near the floor. If you exhaust at the bottom then that hot air will be sucked back in the intake at the top.